# How do I remove the 'required' rules from all form inputs in jQuery Validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

As above, how can I remove all of the required rules from a form using jQuery Validate?

This is what I have at present:

```
var settings = $('form').validate().settings;

//alert(settings.rules.toSource());
for (var i in settings.rules){
    alert(i);
    delete settings.rules.i; 
    // ^ not sure about how to do this properly,
    // and how to just delete the 'required' rule and keep the rest intact
}
```

The function native to jQuery Validate returns an undefined error:

```
$("input, select, textarea").rules('remove','required');
```

Comment: use  $(this).removeClass('required')

Comment: @Amit That won't work as the validation settings aren't running off the input classes.

Comment: Can you tell us why you want to do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As can sometimes be the case, I appear to have stumbled on the answer just after resorting to posting on here.

```
for (var i in settings.rules){
   delete settings.rules[i].required;
}
```

Works.

Comment: How can I use this code in TypeScript? I tried but I am not able to compile my code. I am getting the following error - Type 'RulesDictionary' is not an array type or a string type

Answer (score 27):

And if you don't want to mess with validate's internal settings, you can use the public function in this way:

```
$('input, select, textarea').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('remove', 'required');
});
```

Note that leaving out the second parameter (required) would remove all the rules, not just the "required".

Comment: this one breaks if there are not rules set for that specific input

Comment: agree with @CătălinRădoi. Breaks for me when the rules are not set.

Answer (score 2):

When you need to remove a required input, you need also delete the attr of your input, test this.

`$('element').rules('remove', 'required');
 $('element').removeAttr('required');`

Answer (score 0):

You can disable jquery validate rules globally for client side validation using the ignore property (see validator options https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/). This is useful for testing server side validation.

You can disable all rules

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
  ignore: ":hidden, input, select, textarea"
})
```

This is a jquery selector so you also do,

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
  ignore: ":hidden, input[required], select[required], textarea[required]"
})
```

For additional inputs just add as needed.

You can also remove html validation with something like this for dev environment (since its a slow selector):

```
$("*[required]").removeAttr("required");
$("*[maxlength]").removeAttr("maxlength");
$("*[minlength]").removeAttr("minlength");
$("*[pattern]").removeAttr("pattern");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to remove / reset the red validation text too.

```
function RemoveJQVRule(rulename, inputname) {
   $(`[name="${inputname}"]`).rules('remove', rulename);
   $(`#${inputname.replace('.', '_')}-error`).html("");
}
```

Usage:

```
RemoveJQVRule('required', 'AddressVM.CityId')
```

The dot is when dealing with objects, it can work for simple names normally like 'Address'.